# I only see the download links for DRMed ebooks on my Kobo Library

Tags: kobo

Am I not allowed to download copies of DRM-free books? Do I have to use the app to view them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I messaged Kobo's customer service and got this response

> Thank you for contacting Kobo Customer Care. We are more than happy to
>   assist you.
>
> **The book(s) you have purchased have been released by the publisher in**
>   **the new ePub3 format, which can only be synced through the Kobo cloud**.
>   If you are not using a Kobo device or application, you will not be
>   able to add this book manually. Additionally, ePub3 books are not
>   compatible with some of our older Kobo devices such as the Original,
>   Wifi, and Vox, nor the Kobo app on a Blackberry device.
>
> We apologize for this inconvenience and would be happy to offer you a
>   store credit or refund. Please reply to this email and let us know
>   which you would prefer.

I thought ePub3 is a standard? But I guess that's another issue entirely. At least now I know why those download links were missing.